# Upgrade Ubuntu Kernel from command line

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-12.04

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 on my server. It has Ubuntu kernel 2.6.X running on it. I was trying to update my kernel yesterday. For that I had run the following commands

> sudo do-release-upgrade -c

It returned that I could upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04. Then I run the

> sudo do-release-upgrade command

then I rebooted my system. When I check the system details with

> uname -r

I can see that ubuntu 12.04 is installed on my server. But when I run

> uname -i

It shows that server is still running on kernel 2.6.x

So I see that I have updated to latest version of Ubuntu but still running on old kernel. So how can I upgrade my kernel to the latest version..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

`# sudo apt-cache search linux-image`

and

`# sudo apt-get install linux-image-$version`

should suffice.

Updating of `grub` and `intramfs` should be automatic.

Comment: thanks dawud for your prompt reply. I spoke to the guy from my VPS hosting provider company. His reponse was that the server is built on OpenVZ and because of these the only way to update the kernel is by formatting the server and installing latest build of the OS with latest kernel. Using the commands from terminal we can upgrade the OS but not the kernel. these is what was their reply. 

Are they correct that I cannot update my server(ie server kernel I mean) as they have installed it on openVZ or should I give more time trying to update my server?

Comment: Formatting the server to upgrade the kernel is **overkill**. I've seen VPS providers that give you a list of kernels you can boot from, for example. Don't know about OpenVZ specifics, though.